# How to raster calc on rasterio with two image not on the same band

Tags: python, raster-calculator, rasterio

I want to compute for an NDVI using [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I must use two raster images that are adjacent to each other. They do not have the same sizes. They have a great overlap area which I can calculate NDVI on. One image is slightly shifted from the other. How to calculate raster that are not of the same sizes and does not overlap entirely?

Data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1J3gmJVObv0LVoiUM_JhziD8ip19IB3l3?usp=sharing

EDIT 1: I have this to start with:

```
red_filename = "data/red.tif"
nir_filename = "data/nir.tif"

red_dataset = rasterio.open(red_filename)
nir_dataset = rasterio.open(nir_filename)

red_band = red_dataset.read(1)
nir_band = nir_dataset.read(1)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = pyplot.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,12))
show((red_dataset, 1), ax=ax1, cmap='Reds', title='red_band')
show((nir_dataset, 1), ax=ax2, cmap='Blues', title='nir_band')
```

Comment: Are the two images acquired from the same sensor?

Comment: Yes @Aaron. They are are adjacent captures of the same sensor.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot highlighting the issue you are observing?

Comment: I don't have an error. I need to know how to calculate the ndvi from the two raster. The two images does not have the same shapes. I want to be able to compute ndvi where the two images overlap.

Comment: I would mosaic the images and then calculate NDVI. Alternatively, mosaic the images, tile the images to meet your needs, and then calculate NDVI.

Comment: My data does not have the same bands. My data is just an NIR band and Red band. Both image are just single band and cannot be mosaiced since they are different in band.

Comment: I think I understand your issue. Sounds like you have two images with separate bands (e.g. [/image1-band4.tif, /image1-band3.tif], [/image2-band4.tif, /image2-band3.tif]. If this is the case, you can indeed mosaic the two sets of images, so you will end up with, for example, a mosaiced band 4 and a mosaiced band 3. Then calculate NDVI. More details: https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/lessons/L6/raster-mosaic.html

Comment: Almost. I only have /image1-band4.tif and /image2-band3.tif. I dont have a band3 for image1 and band4 for image2. These images  /image1-band4.tif and /image2-band3.tif have an overlap which I can calculate NDVI on.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do a stacking using osgeo/gdal. When stacked, it will generate a new image with a bounding box that extends to both image. After that you can read both band from the stacked image and perform the calculation. Each band from the stacked image will have 0 values on the extent which it not have original values.

```
from osgeo import gdal
red_filename = "data/red.tif"
nir_filename = "data/nir.tif"
outvrt = '/vsimem/stacked.vrt' #/vsimem is special in-memory virtual "directory"
outtif = 'data/stacked.tif'
tifs = [nir_filename, red_filename] 

outds = gdal.BuildVRT(outvrt, tifs, separate=True)
outds = gdal.Translate(outtif, outds)

stack_filename = "data/stacked.tif"
stack_dataset = rasterio.open(stack_filename)

nir_band = stack_dataset.read(1)
red_band = stack_dataset.read(2)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = pyplot.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,12))
show((red_band), ax=ax1, cmap='Reds', title='red_band')
show((nir_band), ax=ax2, cmap='Blues', title='nir_band')

ndvi = (nir_band - red_band) / (nir_band + red_band)
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(6,8))
show((ndvi), ax=ax, cmap='RdYlGn', title='NDVI')
```